# Calling a function directly takes more time than calling it by a bash script

Tags: c, linux, bash, arm

I'm having a strange problem in the running time of a function. Consider these 2 scenarios:

- I have a library `libfoo.so`, which has a function `foo()`

  1. App (a `C` program) calls `foo()` - takes **X** time
  2. Same app calls a **script** (`script.sh`) that calls the same `foo()` - takes **X/2** time

I call the script by `system("script.sh")` .

What I mean by "running time" is the operations **inside** `foo()` (for example if `foo()` runs some loop then it would be slower in scenario 1).

Why does having the script in the middle takes half the time than calling `foo()` directly? Is there a way to bypass this script and have **X/2** time?

---

**Edit:**

I wrote a sample code, but I can't reproduce the timings. The script still runs faster, but only by 1%.

```
//libfoo.h
void foo();
```

-

```
//libfoo.c
#include "libfoo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void foo()
{
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<1000000000; i++);

    t = clock() - t;
    double total_time = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("foo() total time: %f seconds\n", total_time);
}
```

-

```
//script.sh
./main_for_script
```

-

```
//main_for_script
#include "libfoo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

-

```
//main.c
#include "libfoo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Calling foo() directly...\n");
    foo();
    printf("Calling foo() via script...\n");
    system("./script.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

-

```
//compilation
$CC -c -fpic libfoo.c
$CC -shared -o libfoo.so libfoo.o
$CC -L. -o main main.c -lfoo
$CC -L. -o main_for_script main_for_script.c -lfoo
```

-

```
//Running command
root@imx6:/stackoverflow# ./main
Calling foo() directly...
foo() total time: 8.794843 seconds
Calling foo() via script...
foo() total time: 8.713951 seconds
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Even if you cannot reproduce the timing on readers machines, the context gets clearer if you provide the code.

Comment: What is `foo()`? is it implemented in [tag:c] both scenarios, or [tag:bash] in the second? You can if you want implement a function in c that does something really slow compared to "*the same function*" in say ... [tag:python]. But the code should be posted in order to know better.

Comment: Did you send export this function as an "loadable built-in" (whatever the name of it is).?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - `foo()` is implemented in `C` in both scenarios. I will post some code.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 - I'm not sure what you mean by "loadable built-in", but googling that leads to problems in **script** being slow. My problem is the opposite... Or did you mean anything else?

Comment: @Yunnosch - MCV coming up...

Comment: If the second call runs faster than the first one, the second probably benefits from some kind of caching.

Comment: @ceving - You're right. I flipped the calls and now "via script" runs slower. But that's not the case in my original code. OK I will dig deeper then...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the resources applied for your program is shared when you call foo  but dedicated when you call the .sh file form the system. So one program running and calling library function(foo) as apposed to one program starting a new one with .sh file. Could be OS and thread related issue.

Comment: There is no way to give an answer without even knowing what `foo()` is.